# Start Perview failed camera in react native

Tags: react-native

I have a component that it scans a QR code.this is my code:

```
import QRCodeScanner from 'react-native-qrcode-scanner';
.
.
.
<QRCodeScanner
cameraType={'front'}
onRead={this.onSuccess.bind(this)} />
.
.
.
onSuccess(e) {
console.warn(e.data);
}
```

this is my plist and androidmanifest.xml:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the camera is accessed for the first                     
time</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the    
first time</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the microsphone is accessed for the 
first time</string>
```

androidmanifest.xml:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />   <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="26" />

</manifest>
```

but I receive this error: Start Preview failed camera

How can I resolve that?

Thanks, advance

Comment: did you set configuration for iOS and Android platform? It seems you didn't set info.plist and AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: yes, I did. but I don't know what is it!

Comment: can you post info.plist and androidmanifest.xml here? you can find them on ios and android folder.

Comment: yes, I can. I have added that to the post.

Comment: it's not your info.plist file. :)   just instruction how to configure iOS side for qr-scanner

Comment: I have edited the post.

Comment: did you install react-native-camera and link it ?

Comment: yes, I have installed and imported the react-native-camera.

Comment: very strange... can you share whole project here?